# Using Openssl blowfish encryption algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, blowfish

I am writing code to encrypt the passwords and match encypted password to check if the passwords are weak. I have written encryption code using ECB mode API and it is not working as expected. There are few of the questions I am coming to while debugging my code. The only option I see, I can use is BF_ecb_encrypt.

1) ecb mode works on 8bytes at a time. What if my password has less than 8 characters? should it be padded randomly generated char? or with Zero's? Will it work this way? or any other possible way

2) Snippet:

```
BF_set_key(bfKey, strlen(achSalt), achSalt);
String strBuf;
while (len >= 8)
{
  BF_ecb_encrypt(inStr,buf, bfKey, BF_ENCRYPT);
  len -= 8;
  inStr += 8;
  strBuf += String(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf));
  buf +=8;
}
```

Is there any bug in the code?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You probably want to hash your password rather than encrypt it - that's the standard way of storing passwords so unless you have a very good reason to encrypt, don't do it

Comment: Could you please give a example for the same

Comment: Open ssl includes hash algorithms: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html

Comment: okay. Let me explain my use case in detail:

Comment: I have a database of Username and password (Hashed using blowfish algorithm). Here i want to verify if any of the password is weak. For that only way is to have dictionary of weak passwords, hash them using blowfish algo and match them against the one in database.

Comment: Blowfish does not hash passwords, it encrypts them. Encryption is reversible, use the blowfish key to decrypt the passwords and then check if the actual password is 'weak'.

Answer (score 0):

Where you say:

> 1) ecb mode works on 8bytes at a time. What if my password has less
>   than 8 characters?

why not just set the minimum length to 8 characters for "security" reasons. people often have a password longer than 8 characters because if its longer and more complex, when encrypted its harder to crack.

Comment: You are right Flyphe. However i am using existing database wherein the password could be same as username(having length less than 8 bytes) and that is where i my use case is valid to find if password is weak.

Comment: @Rhexis how to generate bfKey?