# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when using BF_cfb64_encrypt

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, blowfish

I want to encrypt/decrypt files or data that is send over the network with Blowfish using openssl. I use theese functions for this: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BF_options.html

However, i cant get it to work right, i get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when running into 'BF_cfb64_encrypt'

the 'BF_set_key' does run without problems. I guess im doing something wrong with the variables..

here is some of my code:

```
BF_KEY key;

const unsigned char *bf_key_data, *enc_data = new unsigned char[64];
unsigned char *out_data = new unsigned char[64], *ivec = new unsigned char[8];

long curr_length = 32;

int *num = 0;

bf_key_data = (const unsigned char *)"mysecretkey";

BF_set_key(&key, strlen("mysecretkey"), bf_key_data);

enc_data = (const unsigned char *)data.c_str(); // read the data that i want to encrypt from a std::string
ivec[0] = 'f';
ivec[1] = 'f';
ivec[2] = 'f';
ivec[3] = 'f';
ivec[4] = 'f';
ivec[5] = 'f';
ivec[6] = 'f';
ivec[7] = 'f';

BF_cfb64_encrypt(enc_data, out_data, curr_length, &key, ivec, num, BF_DECRYPT); // EXEC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I know this could be done using other functions, but i really want to use theese ones. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `int *num = 0;` should be `int num=0;` and usage down in the `BF_cfb64_encrypt` call should be by-address: `&num`. Further, if you're performing an encryption, should probably use `BF_ENCRYPT` for the final parameter. Just saying...

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Comment: [Using Openssl blowfish encryption algorithm in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980431), [Blowfish crypto messes up first 8 bytes during encryption and decryption](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21189487), [Blowfish C++ does not correctly encrypt/decrypt.. why..?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5225996), [Encrypting and decrypting a message with Blowfish](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20133502), ...